# bash script not doing as a cron, but manually

Tags: linux, bash, path, cron

The script itself is working well, when executed manually. It fails a cron job

```
function ban_this {
while IFS= read -r line
do
printf $line >> /tmp/test.file
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$a") 
}

a=$(journalctl | grep "client @")
ban_this
```

Comment: You are just posting a script, not even indicating which part is not correct, or in what way. If you already suspect a PATH issue, why don't you print the PATH initially, so that you can check it?

Comment: @user1934428  Yes, the original script posted, is irrelevant. WIl replace with this one here. The same problem. I have in the meantime experimented a bit. This looks in fact, the problem: function ban_this {
 while IFS= read -r line
        do
printf $line >> /tmp/test.file
    done < <(printf '%s\n' "$a") 
}

a=$(journalctl | grep "client @")
ban_this    This code executes well, when called manually, but fails as cron job. This can be replicated.

Comment: Don't put these details into a comment, write it in the comment. Also don't forget to explain in what way it fails, and how you invoke it manually, and how you invoke it from cron.

Comment: @user1934428 The sample now works perfect, if executed manually and absolutely nothing, when executed by cron. This is the one and only problem

Comment: What does _absolutely nothing_ exactly mean? Is no statement executed, or are statements executed, and you just don't get any output?

Comment: Aside from this, I don't think it makes sense to discuss thise further, as long as you don't provide **all** the information I asked you in my previous comments.

Comment: it means: executed as cron job "while IFS= read -r line
do
printf $line >> /tmp/test.file
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$a") " fails.  Problem found and corrected

Answer (score 0):

```
function ban_this {
printf %s "$a" |
while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$line"
done
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.